# eclipse complains: Can not find the tag directory "/WEB-INF/tags/" but it really does exist

Tags: jsp, taglib, eclipse-wtp

I have a Maven2 web module as an Eclipse project (more specifically, SpringSource Tool Suite 2.6).  I have a hello.tag in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags.  It's just this:

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
Hello World!
```

I have a Hello.jsp in src/main/webapp.  It's just this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fl" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/" %>
<fl:hello/>
```

If I build and deploy the application, everything works as expected.  The problem is that Eclipse is reporting a problem with the taglib line.  It says:

> Can not find the tag directory
>   "/WEB-INF/tags/"

I have already seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265309/eclipse-cannot-find-the-tag-library-descriptor), but the resolution had to do with the projects natures/facets not being enabled and I believe I have all of the natures I need set up in .project:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven2Nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
</natures>
```

Anyone seen this before or have any ideas what else I should check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this link will help.

http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-26040.html

I think you should check to use the XSD definition (web-app_2_4.xsd) for jsp2.0 and Tomcat5.5

for example:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
```

Comment: If your project is not very large, you may try open it with netbeans 6.9 which is more stable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds exactly like https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338751 .

Comment: That does sound like it.  I current have 3.2.3 and 3.2.4 is in maintenance, but I'll take a look at it soon.

Comment: Now that 3.2.4 is out, does it help? You'd have to manually invoke Validation on your project to remove the old error message.

Comment: It did not help, although it's not clear to me from the bug which component I should be looking at.  I have Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools listed as 3.2.4 and Eclipse Web Developer Tools is 3.2.4, but Eclipse Faceted Project Framework is still 3.2.3 after doing the software update.

Comment: It did help when I also applied the answer supplied by @Nathanphan.  I gave him credit for the answer, but voted you up, too.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned the project by using "Project > Clean..." and it fixed the issue.