# running spring simple example

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to done that tutorial http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/ but I am stuck just before moment when `Hello world` should appear into my browser...

In `pom.xml` I get: `<finalName>ex1</finalName>` so I am going to `http://localhost:8080/ex1/` and get: `HTTP Status 404 - Servlet appServlet is not available`. My package where I keep controller has  a little different name than in article, but maven build `.war` successfully.

I am also probably have some issues with `jstl` so I added to my pom file also:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

but that also didnt help. Another thing what I tried was follow these instruction: [Eclipse "cannot find the tag library descriptor" for custom tags (not JSTL!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265309/eclipse-cannot-find-the-tag-library-descriptor/4744147#4744147) , also without success.

I am using **tomcat 6 @ ubuntu**.

If anyone could heelp me, I would be very thankful.

EDIT:

This is what logs from today tomcat6 looks like:

> INFO: Deploying web application archive ex1.war 2011-08-29 17:13:50
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources INFO:
>   Undeploying context [/ex1] 2011-08-29 17:13:50
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO: Deploying web
>   application archive ex1.war

EDIT:

After rebooting tomcat6 there appears some errors:

```
2011-08-29 17:48:16 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet appServlet as unavailable
2011-08-29 17:48:16 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader
  context: /ex1
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@33c282a1
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
2011-08-29 17:48:16 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /ex1 threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
2011-08-29 17:48:16 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
2011-08-29 17:48:16 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

Comment: Any logs in the server? Catalina.out

Comment: Logs seems to be fine, there was only 2 lines, check update

Comment: What ApplicationServer do you use?

Comment: I can't see the tomcat started part. Are you sure it is starting? what about logs/ex1.log ?

Comment: I dont have that file, just catalina.2011-08-29.log and few others less relevant I think...

Comment: Visit http://localhost:8080 and check whether Tomcat is runing

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - Servlet appServlet is not available. Means that it is not ok. It couldn't start for some reason. What about logs/ex1.log ?

Comment: but tomcat is running for sure, tomcat's examples works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

```
<display-name>ex1</display-name>
```

to web.xml

EDIT:

After addition exception trace:
Check class name of ServletDispatcher and check sprinmwc dependency in pom.xml

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfortunetly there is no change, however maven build is successfull still...

Comment: BTW try to  add war file in deploy directory of Tomcat and then start Tomcat via console. There will many loggs messages. And when catalica will deploy your war it's may print available URL. I'm not sure, but with JBoss it's work

Comment: Now check the class name of ServletDispatcher in web.xml.

Comment: Damn so I have lack springmvc... now it looks fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

can you try adding the following to your pom.xml and accessing

http://localhost:8080/ex1

```
  <build>    
    <finalName>ex1</finalName>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a class not found exception. Do you have Spring-WebMVC jar file in your classpath? Check your maven dependencies.